# Question regarding GM Tubes Calibration Frequency

Tags: calibration, radiation

My friend has has been using  GM Tubes for more than a decade now. He has been calibrating them once per year. But the calibration data reveals that his GM Tubes  would have remained within allowed error range even if he had never calibrated them after the first calibration.
Can I use this operaring experience to calibrate my GM Tubes (same manufacturer, same type, same working environment) after a decade?

I know that calibration frequency is:

1. Recommended by manufacturer.
2. Adopted by end user based on his own experience, as they might have different operating environment.

What is the correct method of defining calibration frequency without risking safety as well as keeping in view economic considerations?

Comment: "without risking safety" ... no.

Comment: Even with components from the same manufacturer, you can't rely on anecdotal data from another person. Your tubes may have been manufactured using different equipment, different operators, different process flows, etc.

Comment: Needs more weird: https://youtu.be/3VKzqAefBVY

Comment: @Alderson what about those detectors about which that observation is. Can that person increase calibration interval based on his experience.